# Number of polynomials with a rational or integral root

Tags: analytic-number-theory, polynomials

Let $f(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ have degree $d$ and naive height (maximum of the absolute values of the coefficients) at most $H$. Is there a known estimate, say in the form of main term + big-O or little-o error term, for the number of such $f(x)$ with a rational root? What about an integer root?

Naively, I think we can obtain an upper bound using the rational root theorem and Dirichlet's estimate of the divisor summatory function:

Let $f(x)=a_dx^d+...+a_1x+a_0$ be as above (so that $a_d\neq 0$). If $a_0=0$ then $f$ is determined by a factor of degree $d-1$ and height at most $H$, of which there are $2H(2H+1)^{d-1}=O\left(H^d\right)$.

Otherwise, if $a_0\neq 0$, by the rational root theorem we can write

$$f(x)=(sx-r)g(x)$$

where $g(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is of degree $d-1$ and height at most $H$, and $\dfrac{r}{s}\in\mathbb{Q}$ satisfies $r\mid a_0$ and $s\mid a_d$.

The degrees of freedom are the coefficients of $g(x)$, so summing over these possibilities and all divisors of $a_0$ and $a_d$ gives $O\left(H^d(\log H)^2\right)$. If we restrict to integral roots then we lose a factor of $\log H$, so an upper bound is $O\left(H^d\log H\right)$.

Is there a known tighter estimate in the literature?

Answer (score 2):

Bary-Soroker and Kozma, Irreducible polynomials of bounded height, https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.05165 write, concerning monic polynomials, "one fixes $n=\deg f$, and the coefficients are i.i.d. random variables taking values uniformly in $\{\,-L,\dotsc,L\,\}$ with $L\to\infty$. We do not know how far back it goes, but it is well-known that the probability that $f$ is irreducible goes to one as $L\to\infty$.

"The state of the art error term is given by Kuba: the probability that $f$ is reducible is $O(L^{-1})$ for $n>2$."

The Kuba reference is  On the distribution of reducible polynomials. Mathematica Slovaca, 59:3 (2009), 349–356. Available at: degruyter.com/0131-6

Comment: Thank you for the reference! This leaves the family of polynomials which are reducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ but have no roots in $\mathbb{Q}$ (or $\mathbb{Z}$). I guess this family is very small in the set of all reducible polynomials, but do you know any quantitative results?